# A* GetNearest() implementation

Tags: unity, mathematics, path-finding

I'm trying to implement pathfinding in my platformer and I'm having trouble coming up with a way to find the nearest node to a world point.

---

I tried this:

```
public Node GetNodeFromPoint(Vector2 point)
    {
        int xGridPoint = Mathf.RoundToInt(point.x / gridWorldSize.x);
        int yGridPoint = Mathf.RoundToInt(point.y / gridWorldSize.y);

        Debug.Log(xGridPoint + " " + yGridPoint);

        return grid[xGridPoint, yGridPoint];
    }
```

But it always gave me `[0,0]`.

This is my "NavGrid" class it creates the grid and is going to set up the links between nodes:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NavGrid : MonoBehaviour {

    public LayerMask unWalkableMask;
    public Vector2 gridWorldSize;
    public float nodeSize;

    public float maxFallLinkLimit = 100f;

    Node[,] grid;

    int gridSizeX;
    int gridSizeY;

    float nodeDiameter;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        nodeDiameter = nodeSize * 2;
        gridSizeX = Mathf.RoundToInt(gridWorldSize.x / nodeDiameter);
        gridSizeY = Mathf.RoundToInt(gridWorldSize.y / nodeDiameter);
        CreateGrid();
        CreateFallLinks();
    }

    private void CreateGrid()
    {
        grid = new Node[gridSizeX, gridSizeY];
        Vector2 worldBottomLeft = transform.position - (Vector3)Vector2.left * gridWorldSize.x / 2 - (Vector3)Vector2.down * gridWorldSize.y / 2;

        for(int x = 0; x < gridSizeX; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < gridSizeY; y++)
            {
                Vector2 worldPoint = worldBottomLeft + Vector2.left * (x * nodeDiameter + nodeSize) + Vector2.down * (y * nodeDiameter + nodeSize);

                bool iswalkable = false;

                if (!Physics2D.CircleCast(worldPoint, nodeSize, Vector2.down, nodeSize/2, unWalkableMask))
                {
                    if (Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(worldPoint.x, worldPoint.y - nodeSize), Vector2.down, nodeDiameter, unWalkableMask))
                    {
                        iswalkable = true;
                    }
                }

                Node node = new Node(iswalkable, worldPoint);

                grid[x, y] = node;
            }
        }
    }

    private void CreateFallLinks()
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < gridSizeX; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < gridSizeY; y++)
            {
                Node node = grid[x, y];
                if (!node.isWalkable) continue;

                if(!grid[x+1,y].isWalkable && !grid[x+1,y-1].isWalkable)
                {
                    Vector2 fallPoint = grid[x + 1, y].worldPosition;

                    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(fallPoint, Vector2.down, maxFallLinkLimit, unWalkableMask);
                    if(hit.collider != null)
                    {
                        node.fallLink = GetNodeFromPoint(hit.point);
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if (!grid[x - 1, y].isWalkable && !grid[x - 1, y - 1].isWalkable)
                {
                    Vector2 fallPoint = grid[x - 1, y].worldPosition;

                    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(fallPoint, Vector2.down, maxFallLinkLimit, unWalkableMask);
                    if (hit.collider != null)
                    {
                        node.fallLink = GetNodeFromPoint(hit.point);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Node GetNodeFromPoint(Vector2 point)
    {
        int xGridPoint = Mathf.RoundToInt(point.x / nodeSize);
        int yGridPoint = Mathf.RoundToInt(point.y / nodeSize);

        Debug.Log(xGridPoint + " " + yGridPoint);

        return grid[xGridPoint, yGridPoint];
    }

    public void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position, new Vector3(gridWorldSize.x, gridWorldSize.y, 1));

        if (grid != null)
        {
            foreach (Node n in grid)
            {
                if (n.isWalkable)
                {
                    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
                    Gizmos.DrawRay(new Vector2(n.worldPosition.x, n.worldPosition.y - nodeSize), new Vector2(0, -nodeDiameter));
                    Gizmos.color = Color.cyan;
                    Gizmos.DrawCube(n.worldPosition, Vector3.one * (nodeDiameter * 0.9f));
                    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
                    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(n.worldPosition, nodeSize / 2);
                }

                if(n.fallLink != null)
                {
                    Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
                    Gizmos.DrawLine(n.worldPosition, n.fallLink.worldPosition);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried coldSteel's answer but it gave me a array index out of range error because it world return a negative number.

This is the node class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Node {

    public bool isWalkable = false;
    public Vector2 worldPosition;
    public Node fallLink = null;

    public Node(bool isWalkable, Vector2 worldPosition)
    {
        this.isWalkable = isWalkable;
        this.worldPosition = worldPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: To help you with this, we'll need to know the range of your `point` argument and the value of `gridWorldSize` - it sounds like they're not in compatible units, causing their quotient to always be so small it rounds to zero.

Comment: gridWorldSize is the "area" the grid covers in world space.

Comment: Wait, the size of the entire grid, not the size of one cell? That sounds like your problem.

Comment: I tried it with the node size and that didn't work either.

Comment: "Didn't work" isn't enough for us to diagnose the problem. Can you update your question to include a minimal, complete, verifiable example of the issue that we can reproduce in a new project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [This](https://github.com/SebLague/Pathfinding) tutorial there is a good way of doing it.

```
public Node NodeFromWorldPoint(Vector3 worldPosition) {
        float percentX = (worldPosition.x + gridWorldSize.x/2) / gridWorldSize.x;
        float percentY = (worldPosition.z + gridWorldSize.y/2) / gridWorldSize.y;
        percentX = Mathf.Clamp01(percentX);
        percentY = Mathf.Clamp01(percentY);

        int x = Mathf.RoundToInt((gridSizeX-1) * percentX);
        int y = Mathf.RoundToInt((gridSizeY-1) * percentY);
        return grid[x,y];
    }
```

It's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56175463/how-does-this-method-get-a-node-from-a-a-grid) nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You are dividing a point by a grid size - thus you get a 0,0 because I assume that grid size is much larger than a point.

What you want to do is: 
To take your point in World coordinates and divide it by a GridCellSize.

For example your CellSize is [3,3] 
And your point is [6,0]

XCoord = 6/3 = 2

YCoord = 0/3 = 0